How to reference an author in .bib
I have a .bib reference like this:
    @Report{wef2023,
  title = {Future of Jobs Report, 2023},
  author = {World Economic Forum},
  institution = {World Economic Forum},
  address = {91-93 route de la Capite,CH-1223 Cologny/Geneva, Switzerland},
  year = {2023},
  url = {https://www.weforum.org/publications/the-future-of-jobs-report-2023/},
  note = {ISBN-13: 978-2-940631-96-4},
}

and it appears on bibliography as
Forum, World Economic. 2023. “Future of Jobs Report, 2023.” 91-93 route de la Capite,CH-1223 Cologny/Geneva, Switzerland: World Economic Forum. https://www.weforum.org/publications/the-future-of-jobs-report-2023/.
but I want to reference it as
World Economic Forum. 2023. “Future of Jobs Report, 2023.” 91-93 route de la Capite,CH-1223 Cologny/Geneva, Switzerland: World Economic Forum. https://www.weforum.org/publications/the-future-of-jobs-report-2023/.
without changing global options for names in bibliography, only change this one. Is it possible?
Thank you,
Juan
